# Why does the path sometimes contain icons in Open Recent? Has anyone else even seen this?

Tags: macos, path, textedit

Sometimes when I use `Open Recent` in the `File` menu of TextEdit, the path appears as a long trail of icons. Often (as shown below) it is doubled, identical on two lines.

This seems to happen spontaneously, doesn't look like that a few minutes before or later, and nothing notable (that I'm aware of) has happened.

I've seen this happen for a USB flash drive, and also for local files on my laptop's hard drive.

**Question:** Why does this happen, and does it have any significance that I should be aware of?

[image: Open Recent]

**edit:** This *might have tended* to be associated with heavy use or times when available disk space is low (on USB or local) but I can't be certain; I don't remember and it hasn't happened recently.

Comment: I've seen this happen before; however, I believe if was a fluke and anomaly which I was not able to recreate. YMMV

Comment: @user3439894 I was running an old OS at the time, this may have been an "artifact" and have been fixed. Thank you very much for the verification!